# Always Get Null On Response Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

firstly sorry for bad english, i try to making an app using a bar chart i have to get the data for bar from Api, so i use retrofit for calling the data and put the data on the bar, but i stucked in where when i call the data is null, but if i open the web of api it showed on my browser

this is my ApiService.kt

```
import com.abisayuti.coalyardstock.service.IssueRecieve.ResponseIssue
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface ApiService {

    @GET("2019/coal/index.php/api/monitoring/shipping/")
    fun fetchAllShipping(): Call<List<ResponseCS1k>>

    @GET("2019/coal/index.php/api/monitoring/issue_stock?unit=u12")
    fun fetchAllCoal(): Call<ResponseIssue>
}
```

this is my ResponseIssue.kt

```
package com.abisayuti.coalyardstock.service.IssueRecieve

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class ResponseIssue(

    @field:SerializedName("name_coal")
    val nameCoal: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("qty_stock")
    val qtyStock: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("name_vendor")
    val nameVendor: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("timestamp")
    val timestamp: String? = null
)
```

and this is  setDataBar() on my IRFragmentUnit_1K.kt

```
internal fun setDataBar() {
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        httpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor)
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseurl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        val call = service.fetchAllCoal()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseIssue> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseIssue>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("onFailure", "onFailure ${t.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseIssue>, response: Response<ResponseIssue>) {
                val respon = response.body()!!
                val y = respon.qtyStock.toString()
                val name = respon.nameVendor.toString()
                Log.d("OnResponse", "ada ${name}")
                Log.d("onResponse", "ada ${y}")


                val bargroup = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                val bargroup2 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                val bargroup3 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                val bargroup4 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                val bargroup5 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                val bargroup6 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                val bargroup7 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()


                bargroup.add(BarEntry(0f, 0f, name))
                bargroup2.add(BarEntry(1f, 0f, name))
                bargroup3.add(BarEntry(2f, 0f, name))
                bargroup4.add(BarEntry(3f, 0f, name))
                bargroup5.add(BarEntry(4f, 0f, name))
                bargroup6.add(BarEntry(5f, 0f, name))
                bargroup7.add(BarEntry(6f, 0f, name))


                // creating dataset for Bar Group
                val barDataSet = BarDataSet(bargroup, name)
                val barDataSet2 = BarDataSet(bargroup2, name)
                val barDataSet3 = BarDataSet(bargroup3, name)
                val barDataSet4 = BarDataSet(bargroup4, name)
                val barDataSet5 = BarDataSet(bargroup5, name)
                val barDataSet6 = BarDataSet(bargroup6, name)
                val barDataSet7 = BarDataSet(bargroup7, name)


                val data =
                    BarData(barDataSet, barDataSet2, barDataSet3, barDataSet4, barDataSet5, barDataSet6, barDataSet7)
                val textSize = "10"
                bar_chart_unit3.data = data
                bar_chart_unit3.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
                bar_chart_unit3.xAxis.labelCount = 11
                bar_chart_unit3.xAxis.enableGridDashedLine(5f, 5f, 0f)
                bar_chart_unit3.axisRight.enableGridDashedLine(5f, 5f, 0f)
                bar_chart_unit3.axisLeft.enableGridDashedLine(5f, 5f, 0f)
                bar_chart_unit3.description.isEnabled = false
                bar_chart_unit3.animateY(1000)
                bar_chart_unit3.legend.isEnabled = true
                bar_chart_unit3.legend.textSize = textSize.toFloat()
                bar_chart_unit3.setPinchZoom(true)
                bar_chart_unit3.data.setDrawValues(false)
            }

        })
```

in Logcat is showing this

```
D/OnResponse: ada null
D/onResponse: ada null
```

this is my response json

```
[
{
qty_stock: "500",
name_vendor: "BUKIT ASAM",
name_coal: "COAL YARD I",
timestamp: "2019-03-01",
},
{
qty_stock: "150",
name_vendor: "BUKIT ASAM",
name_coal: "COAL YARD I",
timestamp: "2019-03-02",
},
{
qty_stock: "20",
name_vendor: "JORONG",
name_coal: "COAL YARD I",
timestamp: "2019-03-01",
},
{
qty_stock: "400",
name_vendor: "SSP",
name_coal: "COAL YARD IV",
timestamp: "2019-03-01",
},
]
```

Comment: post your json respose

Comment: @Naveen ok i have post it

Comment: Your response is array not an object. Change your `Call<ResponseIssue>` to `Call<List<ResponseIssue>>` and change your retrofit implementation also.

Comment: @Naveen how i change this one  `override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ResponseIssue>>, response: Response<List<ResponseIssue>>) { val respon = response.body()!! val y = respon.qtyStock.toString()` , cause the qtyStock is can't called after i change it to `<List<RespnseIssue>>`

Comment: You are receiving a list of ResponseIssues, that means you either fetch a specific one (first?) or iterate over them with a `for` loop.

Comment: see my answer. @FatahKhair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is an array not an object.

Change your interface like below

```
@GET("2019/coal/index.php/api/monitoring/issue_stock?unit=u12")
  fun fetchAllCoal(): Call<List<ResponseIssue>>
}
```

Then in your `onResponse` get your variable like below.

```
 val respon = response.body()!! 
 val y = respon[0].qtyStock.toString(),
 val name = respon[0].nameVendor.toString()
```

Or use for loop to iterate all values from arraylist.

Comment: pls help (again) i got this in logcat `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $` i sure this is not from ur answer

Comment: Have you changed your retrofit on Response with List<ResponseIssue>?

Comment: this error refers you are parsing object not an array.

Comment: Not only in onResponse. Also change to `call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ResponseIssue>>`  with complete new implementation. Don't overite  with existing callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
  internal fun setDataBar() {
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    httpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor)
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseurl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
    val service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    val call = service.fetchAllCoal()
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ResponseIssue>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ResponseIssue>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Response", "${t.message}")

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ResponseIssue>>, response: Response<List<ResponseIssue>>) {
            val respon = response.body()!!
            val y = respon[0].qtyStock!!.toFloat()
            val name = respon[0].nameVendor.toString()
            Log.d("Response", "Name ${name}")
            Log.d("Response", "Y ${y}")
         }
    })  }
```